# Возникла ошибка и не знаю как исправить

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress, http

Ошибка:

> "Failed to set referrer policy: The value '' is not one of 'no-referrer', 'no-referrer-when-downgrade', 'origin', 'origin-when-cross-origin', 'same-origin', 'strict-origin', 'strict-origin-when-cross-origin', or 'unsafe-url'. The referrer policy has been left unchanged."

Выводиться в консоль браузера, и при этом не работает js.
Помогите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

нужны хедеры в php:

```
<?php
   header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
   header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *");
```

Правда mozilla, вроде как не понимает Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *, нужно указывать хост с которого обращаешься